# How can i shorten my code for various winform calls in MDI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a mdi where i have several line of code like the given below. Only chage is Form object which is being opened. So I want to all this work using only single function defination. 
When I tries to capture sender it gives me ToolStipMenuItem here. But I want its sender to be form name  so that I can open its corresponding form.

```
private void purchaseInvoiceToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Forms.PurchaseInvoice purinv = new DigitalInvy.Forms.PurchaseInvoice();
    purinv.Show();
}

private void lederGroupsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Forms.LedgerGroup lgrp = new DigitalInvy.Forms.LedgerGroup();
    lgrp.Show();
}

private void voucherEntryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Forms.VoucherEntry ventry = new DigitalInvy.Forms.VoucherEntry();
    ventry.Show();
}

private void currencyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Forms.CurrencyMaster currency = new DigitalInvy.Forms.CurrencyMaster();
    currency.Show();
}

private void countryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Forms.CountryMaster country = new DigitalInvy.Forms.CountryMaster();
    country.Show();
}
```

I Want to do it something like this

```
private void cMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(sender.GetType()==Form)
  {
    Forms.CountryMaster country = new DigitalInvy.Forms.CountryMaster();
    country.Show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting all these small Click event handlers because you used the designer to create the event handlers.  It is easy to get rid of them if you write the event assignment yourself.  For example:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
      purchaseInvoiceToolStripMenuItem.Click += (o,e) => createChild(new frmPurchaseInvoice());
      ledgerGroupToolStripMenuItem.Click += (o, e) => createChild(new frmLedgerGroup());
      // etc..
    }
    private void createChild(Form frm) {
      frm.MdiParent = this;
      frm.Show();
    }
  }
```

If you're still on C# 2.0 then you can use an anonymous method:

```
  purchaseInvoiceToolStripMenuItem.Click += delegate { createChild(new frmPurchaseInvoice()); };
```

Comment: @Hans: (o,e) => createChild(new frmPurchaseInvoice()); What does this line mean. Please elaborate

Comment: It is a lambda expression.  If you're still on C# 2.0 then you can use an anonymous method.  Post updated with an example.

Answer (score 2):

How about this? If some of your forms need constructor arguments it'll make life slightly trickier, but you could have a non-generic overload taking a `Func<Form>` to say how to build the form to show.

```
private static void AssociateBuilder<T>(ToolStripMenuItem item)
    where T : Form, new()
{
    item.Click += () => new T().Show();
}

AssociateBuilder<PurchaseInvoice>(purchaseInvoiceToolsStripMenuItem);
AssociateBuilder<Ledger>(ledgerGroupsToolStripMenuItem);
// etc
```

Comment: @Jon: Please put some torch on using  "where T : Form, new() " I have no idea about all that you wrote

Comment: @Shantanu Trygoogling for "c# generics".

Comment: @Damian: I am new to generics although, I just want to know is  "Form, new()" syntax a part of generics or it has some significance. I know little bit concept about generics

Comment: @Shantanu: Those are *type constraints* on the generic type parameter T. It's a bit much to explain in a comment though - I suggest you look it up in a C# book.

Comment: Thx a lot, I will have a look at it now